# Better way to map Java object to object

Tags: java, algorithm

I have java client object exposed to clients something like

```
public abstract class Vehicle{
    string id;
    string name;
    Enginer engine;
} 

public class MotorVehicle extends Vehicle {
    int numOfWheels;
}

public class Engine {
    Rotor rotor;
    Stator stator;
    AirGap airgap;
}
```

Now I have business level layer which is kind of same structure but little different in nature.

```
public abstract class VehicleBusinessModel{
    string id;
    string name;
} 

public class MotorVehicleBusinessModel extends VehicleBusinessModel {
    int numOfWheels;
}

public class EngineBusinessModel {
    Rotor rotor;
    Stator stator;
    AirGap airgap;
    Windings windings;
}
```

What will be best way to validate client structure and then convert to business structure ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a project, I would use [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/apimappings.html) or [Orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/intro.html)

If you have lower expectation on performances, you can use [Apache Commons Beanutils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763278/how-to-use-beanutils-copyproperties), which is easier to use.